# Bootstrap Navbar overflows and breaks links when overflow is hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar that overflows on mobile, when I set my css to hide the overflow, the button links break. I am at a total loss. Here is my navbar code. Here is a link to the [site.](http://goodedevelopment.com) I would love if anyone has the opportunity to help thanks.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button id="btnCollapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
          <h1 class="navbar-brand">Goode Development</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a class="a" href="#homey">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="a" href="#porty">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a class="a" href="#abouty">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="a" href="#conty">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
  height: 125px;
background-color:#0d0d0d !important;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: relative!important;
  left: 45px!important;
  bottom: 10px!important;
  font-size: 4em!important;
  color: white!important;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  right: 475px;
  top: 66px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

#myNavbar {
    background-color: #0d0d0d ;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    left: 0 !important;
  }
  .nav li a {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
    color: white;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: -20px !important;
    left: -10px !important;
  }
  .navbar {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
    color: #0d0d0d;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
  .collapsing,
  .in {
    background-color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
  }
  .collapsing ul li a,
  .in ul li a {
    color: white!important;
  }
  .collapsing ul li a:hover,
  .in ul li a:hover {
    color: orange!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "navbar that overflows on mobile" mean? Your page seems to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust you're viewport meta tag for flawless responsive display.

You're currently having:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Adding of minimum, maximum scale, and the user scalability to the meta tag will fix your problem.

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Many blessings to you! That worked perfectly thank you so much!